# I can't force form to submit

Tags: html

My form doesn't perform submit by some reason, here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47aosvk8/)

```
<form action="http://google.com/start/upload" name=formupload id=formupload  autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">    <table style="border:1px solid #cccccc">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Upload Expense</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>File</td>
        <td><input name="file" type="file" value="Upload">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload"  /></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Umm... the URL doesn't exist and throws a 404 error.

Comment: I think OP used google.com as an example, I don't think it's the intended url.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the Javascript console. The error you are getting is:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/47aosvk8/' was loaded over HTTPS,
but requested an insecure form action 'http://google.com/start/upload'.
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

You can correct this by changing the submission URL to use HTTPS instead of HTTP.

After correcting this, the form submits, although leads to a 404 (Not Found) page.